# How to fix index error for this code in python + slow learning model?

Tags: python

I am creating a model to classify wine data.
I am also new to coding.
I have 6 different classes for the ouput variable however I get an index error.

How do I fix this?
Furthermore, when I execute the model it is very slow learning, how can I fix this? Below is the code + error

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.layers import Dropout
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3)

# number of wine classes
classifications = 6

# load dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt('winered.csv', delimiter=",")

# split dataset into sets for testing and training
X = dataset[:,1:12]
Y = dataset[:,0:1]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=5)

# convert output values to one-hot
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train-1, classifications)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test-1, classifications)


# creating model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=11, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(classifications, activation='softmax'))

# compile and fit model
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=15, epochs=5000, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

Expected that model would run but instead got the following error: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-86f94430e936> in <module>()
     20 
     21 # convert output values to one-hot
---> 22 y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train-1, classifications)
     23 y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test-1, classifications)
     24 

/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.pyc in to_categorical(y, num_classes, dtype)
     32     n = y.shape[0]
     33     categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
---> 34     categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
     35     output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
     36     categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)

IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`keras.utils.to_categorical` raises this exception when the given labels contain more classes than what you specify as `num_classes` (in your case the `classifications` you're passing).

You could check with

```
print(np.unique(Y))  # or y_test / y_train
```

whether you really just have 6 unique class labels and if there are any "gaps". It could be that you need to clean up the labels you're reading from the txt before moving on.

Regarding your second question:

> Furthermore, when I execute the model it is very slow learning, how can I fix this?

You would need to be more specific about what *slow* means for you, e.g. slower than another model? Slower than on another system?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying I will check it now!

Comment: I have looked in to the print function. It returns the following: 
[3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8.].

Comment: What is your suggestion to do next, do I need to clean up the labels?

Comment: You could transform ```Y``` to the range [0, ..., 5] by doing something like ```Y -= Y.min()``` before you do the training and test split. Then you just need to keep that in mind when you use the trained model. A prediction of label 0 would correspond to a 3 in your .txt file and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get the following error though TypeError: _amin() takes at most 5 arguments (7 given) when using before traintest split codeline: Y -= Y.min(0,1,2,3,4,5). So know in theory an outcome of 0 would be label 3, 1 label 4, 2 label 5, 3 label 6, 4 label 7 and 5 label 8 (just to verify my thinking process I wrote everything).

Comment: ```Y -= Y.min()``` is enough. It subtracts Y's smallest value (in your case 3) from all labels, thus remapping 3 -> 0, 4 -> 1 and so on. So, no arguments inside the min() needed.

Comment: Thank you again for being so kind to share this knowledge! I am testing the model now and will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: I am having another problem with the learning rate (accuracy gain per epoch). After 6 epoch's the loss, accuracy, val_loss and val_acc stay the same. Epoch 6/5000
1071/1071 [==============================] - 0s 446us/step - loss: 1.5058 - acc: 0.4416 - val_loss: 1.5243 - val_acc: 0.3939

Comment: I'm afraid that is a problem that goes way beyond this question. It could be that your model is not appropriate, that your optimization parameters need refinement or even that this is the best you can do for your dataset. I'd suggest looking for some machine learning tutorials or lectures to get a better idea about what you could do.